# How can I get the visible height of a font?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a price calculator depending on the text size. The problem using HTML is that the fonts don't show correct margins. They have some weird space around them or some fonts just overlap that space.

In the image it can be seen that the blue rectangle is the area that HTML uses for the text and JavaScript reads that size, but I need the actual size of the characters' height without the spaces around (red rectangle).

[image]

Comment: Take the height of the container, not the text

Comment: Imo, it looks like more of image processing